# Visual Studio: Syncing Projects with OneDrive and "Having the mark of the web"

Tags: visual-studio, onedrive

I develop a few small projects in Visual Studio solo and for my needs using a repo like GitHub or Azure Repos just seems a little over the top. I therefore save my projects to OneDrive and develop my projects and when ready to publish and move onto the next build, just copy the existing project directory for version control and start work on to the next version.

However quite often I get stung when building projects

`Couldn't process file <file>.resx due to its being in the Internet or Restricted zone or having the mark of the web on the file. Remove the mark of the web if you want to process these files.`

I then have to copy the director out of OneDrive to an unsynced area such as C:\Temp and it builds just fine but then has the issue of remembering to copy back my modified project once done. There seems to be no clear cause of it and the file properties does not have the usual 'Unblock' option:

[image]

Has anyone come across this with OneDrive, or any suggestions as to why it's happening? I'm sure the main suggestions would be use a repo solution but this method works just fine for me other than this issue so I'd ideally like to get a solution using OneDrive.

**Edit:** To confirm I've added my OneDrive path into the Visual Studio trusted locations area and tried adding file://[pc-name] into my local intranet trusted addresses area without any success.

Answer (score 1):

My problem is IDENTICAL to yours. I have tried adding the pc to the safe sites list, I've tried adding to trusted location, I don't have the unblock checkbox that many people mention, I also tried using a powershell script to unblock the file. No luck. The only solution was to do a repair of Visual Studio. That fixed the issue for me so that it stopped happening.

Comment: How did you repair VS? Reinstall it? Reinstall your OS and VS?